# Linear constraints in Rcgmin

Tags: r

I am using the package Rcgmin to do a non linear optimization. I want to impose a linear constraint that the sum of the parameters should be equal to a value say x. How can I implement that?

Comment: If you are not married to `Rcgmin` I answered exactly the same question [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494083/r-optimization-with-equality-and-inequality-constraints/30494600#30494600) using the `Rsolnp` package.

Comment: I started working on this problem using Rsolnp only. However it simply would'nt give a result. I had asked this question. If you can help me in anyway understanding where I am going wrong Il be really grateful. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346385/using-rsolnp-for-optimization

Comment: Sure, I ll give it a look later on in the day.

Comment: I just answered your question.